# Pressing MENU button pops up voice search

Tags: settings, menu

I am using LG-P509 with Android 2.2.2..

from last week on pressing the MENU button, I get the "Voice search" app opened up. Be it in home page or in any application. This gives trouble as I couldn't use any of the options in any application. For example, if I am in Mail application (exchange), where I need to use MENU button for options (like forward mail), pressing MENU pops up voice search. I searched the settings but couldn't find any way to get this corrected.

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Did you install a custom rom? I ask because my phone, the Optimus V for Virgin Mobile, has a counterpart for Sprint called the Optimus S. Their Home and Menu buttons are swapped, but they are otherwise duplicate phones. So a rom for one can work on the other, except you have to worry about keys being mapped to the wrong device.